# Javascript function not being called using onsubmit in html form

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a pretty simple html file with a validation function in javascript that I am trying to make execute when the form is submitted.  However, I can not get the is_checked() function to run as evidence by no console log statements being executed.  I am using Eclipse and an Apache TomCat 7 server which is properly executing all jsp, servlet, and html code but no javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function is_checked() { 
    console.log("is_checked() was called");
    var taskChecked = document.getElementByID('task').checked;
    var projectChecked = document.getElementByID('project').checked;
    var autoChecked = document.getElementByID('auto').checked;
    var manualChecked = document.getElementByID('manual').checked;

    console.log("taskChecked " + taskChecked);
    console.log("projectChecked " + projectChecked);
    console.log("manualChecked " + manualChecked);
    console.log("autoChecked " + autoChecked);


    if((taskChecked === "true" || projectChecked === "true") 
     && (autoChecked === "true" || manualChecked === "true")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Must select task or project and either auto or manual!');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return is_checked()" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Process Level: </td>
      <td>
       <input type="radio" name="process" value="task" id="task">Task
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="radio" name="process" value="project"
          id="project">Project
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Method Type: </td>
        <td>
         <input type="radio" name="method" value="auto" id="auto">Auto
       </td>
        <td>
         <input type="radio" name="method" value="manual" 
             id="manual">Manual
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea name="ids" rows="15" cols="10"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you have is_checked() function in the form tag and in the submit tag? its doing it twice; just have it in the form tag.

Comment: I tried both methods and just forgot to remove it when I copied the code into the textarea.  It is my understanding that onsubmit is what should be used in the form tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: 
`document.getElementByID` should be replaced with `document.getElementById`

Btw, you are calling the function twice, you can remove the `onClick` in the submit input

Comment: Wow If I had enough points to down grade my own question I would.  The ID instead of Id was the problem. Thanks for the close eye on that one.